# node console.log / util.inspect for nested Object / Array

Tags: javascript, node.js

For the nested Object or Array

```
var obj = {
  foo:
  {
    foo:
    {
      foo:
      {
        foo:
        {
          foo:
          {
            foo: 'foo'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
console.log(obj);
util.debug(obj);
util.debug(util.inspect(obj));
```

The `console.log` or `util.debug` + `util.inspect`

```
{ foo: { foo: { foo: [Object] } } }
DEBUG: [object Object]
DEBUG: { foo: { foo: { foo: [Object] } } }
```

Under a certain depth, it shows just `[Object]` with no further detail.

This is always annoying on debugging since I can't investigate the actual value.

Why does `node` (or V8) implements like this? and Is there any work-around?

Thanks.

---

EDIT:
I received a suggestion

`console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));`

The result

`{"foo":{"foo":{"foo":{"foo":{"foo":{"foo":"foo"}}}}}}`

It sort of works, but obviously the whole is `stringify`ed, and probably I couldn't do this for all object output on debugging. Not generic method.

---

EDIT2:

solution:

`console.log(util.inspect(obj,{ depth: null }));`

output:

`{ foo: { foo: { foo: { foo: { foo: { foo: 'foo' } } } } } }`

cool. This is what I want!

Comment: Did you tried console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)) ?

Comment: Thanks, I edit my Q. please check it out.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`util.inspect()` takes a second `options` argument, where you can specify `depth`. The default is 2.

http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options

So:

```
util = require('util');
var obj = { foo: { foo: { foo: { foo: { foo: { foo: 'foo' } } } } } };
console.log(util.inspect(obj, {depth:12}));
```

... yields:

```
{ foo: { foo: { foo: { foo: { foo: { foo: 'foo' } } } } } }
```

Comment: Cool. Thank you very much. Your answer is checked! I would set the `depth` `null` though. I edited my Q.

Comment: Be careful with `depth:null`, as many times data structures are circular and you'll end up in an endless loop. But if you printing something that you created go ahead :-)

Comment: The default depth is 2.

Comment: True, my bad. I wrap this in my projects with 8. Fixed my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `JSON.stringify`:

```
var obj = {
  foo:
  {
    foo:
    {
      foo:
      {
        foo:
        {
          foo:
          {
            foo: 'foo'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Result:

```
{"foo":{"foo":{"foo":{"foo":{"foo":{"foo":"foo"}}}}}}
```